# Windows form freezing when trying to use multithreading to populate large data set into a combox?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, windows-forms-designer, invoke

I'm trying to populate a list of around 3000 words into a windows form combobox dropdown menu. It was taking a long time doing it in one iteration loop, so i decided to use multi threading to have a thread do the same work on a third of the list. It runs faster, but im noticing it freezing a lot when the threads are running. Im not sure if it an issue with locking or if it just takes long to populate a combobox item list.

Ive tried using method invokers, but I feel like im using them wrong in this case.

I have these threads started:

```
Thread threadmid = new Thread(splitMidThird);
Thread threadtop = new Thread(splitTopThird);

threadmid.Start();
threadtop.Start();

private void splitMidThird()
{
  int thirds = totalPartNumber.Count() / 3;
  if (PartNumber_Text.InvokeRequired)
  {
    PartNumber_Text.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
      for (int index = thirds; index <= thirds * 2; index++)
      {                                
        PartNumber_Text.Items.Add(totalPartNumber.ElementAt(index));
      }
    }));
  }
  return;
}

private void splitTopThird()
{
  int thirds = totalPartNumber.Count() / 3;
  if (PartNumber_Text.InvokeRequired)
  {
    PartNumber_Text.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
      for (int index = thirds * 2; index <= totalPartNumber.Count() - 1; index++I)
      {                        
        PartNumber_Text.Items.Add(totalPartNumber.ElementAt(index));
      }
    }));
  }
  return;
}
```

The form just freezes when i try this.

Comment: Did you try the simple way and just use the word list as a datasource?

Comment: is the datasource the same as the combobox items list? Im not trying to connect from a database.

Comment: Have you tried [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)? 
 Something like: `PartNumber_Text.Items.AddRange(totalPartNumber.ToArray());`

Comment: There is only one UI thread, so the additional threads are pointless.  When you call BeginInvoke, that says, "run this on the thread that owns the control".  The thread that owns the control is the one and only UI thread, so your threads simply get cued up and run sequentially back on the main UI thread itself...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks that worked so quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8) method:

> When using this method to add items to the collection, you do not need
>   to call the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods to optimize performance.

Something like:

```
PartNumber_Text.Items.AddRange(totalPartNumber.ToArray());
```